# How to show equipotential of two point charges is a sphere of radius $R$ about the centre?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential

If a charge $q_{1}$ is placed at a position $z_{1}$ on the z-axis and a second charge $q_{2}$ placed at position $z_{2}$ , where $q_{2} = −q_{1}\sqrt{z_{2}/z_{1}}$. Then how can we show that the spherical geometric surface of radius $R$ = $\sqrt{z_{2}z_{1}}$ about the origin is the equipotential surface?

I have tried showing the radius is $\sqrt{z_{2}z_{1}}$ by letting the potentials equal each other on the opposite sides, however I'm looking for a more complete proof. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove there is an equipotential sphere between two point charges](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/349246/prove-there-is-an-equipotential-sphere-between-two-point-charges)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the problem of determining the potential outside a grounded conducting sphere of radius $R$, containing a point charge $q$ a distance $a$ from its center.
Thus we need to solve Poisson's equation with boundary conditions:

- $V(R)=0$
- $V \rightarrow 0$ as $r \rightarrow \infty$

We consider an entirely different problem, which will hopefully solve Poisson's equation and the above boundary conditions. We replace the spherical conductor by a charge $q'=kq$ a distance $b$ from the center of the sphere.

The potential of this configuration is:
\begin{equation}
    V(\textbf{r}) = \frac{q}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\bigg(\frac{q}{r_+} + \frac{kq}{r_-}\bigg)
\end{equation}
where:
\begin{align}
r_+ &= \sqrt{r^2+a^2-2ra\cos \theta}\\
r_-&=\sqrt{r^2+b^2-2rb\cos \theta}
\end{align}

Imposing the first boundary condition with $r=R$ you will find that
\begin{align}
  b=\frac{R^2}{a}, \ k=-\frac{R}{a}
\end{align}
But this is exactly the problem you proposed of the two charges on the z-axis! Hence, it follows that the surface at radius $R$ will be an equipotential (which we set to be $V=0$), as this was the case when we put a conductor and image charge.

Comment: This is a complete answer to a homework-like question.   Please rewrite in such a way that a reader can understand the approach, but don't do all their work for them.

Comment: i've changed it so that I don't show how the equations are solved. Is it better now?

Answer (score 1):

Write down an equation for the potential at any point in space. Set this equation equal to some constant C, and analyze the resulting relationship between x, y, and z. Compare this to the well-known equation of a sphere at the origin.

EDIT:

$$4\pi\epsilon_0V(x,y,z)=\frac{q_1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-z_1)^2}}-\frac{q_1\sqrt{z_2/z_1}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-z_2)^2}}$$

On the surface that you described, $x^2+y^2+z^2=z_1z_2$. Plug this into the above equation and show that the result is a constant. It will require you to multiply out the $(z-z_2)^2$ and $(z-z_1)^2$ terms, as well as absorbing the $\sqrt{z_2/z_1}$ into the denominator.

Comment: I still don't see how this explicitly shows the radius is that though. Of course your method makes complete sense but it seems long winded.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this is the method that's commonly used for such purposes. The equation of a sphere (centered about the origin) is $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$. Compare the form of your equation (which, again, you derive by the setting the expression for the potential at an arbitrary point in space to a constant) to the sphere equation. The radius of the equipotential sphere will be immediately apparent.

As far as being long-winded, you can probably do the algebra in less time than it took you to post the question in MathJax :)

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but would you mind explicity showing this in your answer section. It would be much appreciated!

Comment: No problem. You were right -- the resulting equation is quite difficult to solve explicitly for $x^2+y^2+z^2$. Nonetheless, I edited my original answer with the outline of a simple proof. All that's missing is a few simple algebraic steps. I worked it out on my own, and the math works out. Let me know if my answer suffices.