# Force between Point Charge and a Neutral Conducting Sphere

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, method-of-images

My question is simply an extension of this [SE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/193204/a-point-charge-near-a-conducting-sphere); I don't understand why $q'+q''=0$ (both charges of hypothetical construct) for the **sphere to be neutral.**

I'm trying to find a parallel between the following two cases:

1. Point charge ($q$), and a conducting sphere.
2. Point charge ($q$), an **image** charge $q'$ and another charge $q''$ (to get the desired potential on the spherical surface of radius $R$, centered at $q''$

Please help me understand this better. Thank you!